# Need to use information from one qry to dictate an action on another

Tags: sql-server, function, aggregate-functions, join

Ok so this is going to sound a little complicated. I want to somehow put some kind of function that will divide a table value by two when its Policy number matches up with a policy number in another table.
Here is the query where I want that functions

```
SELECT 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.POLICY_NO, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SUB_PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SchedNP,
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.ProdType, 
Sum(qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfAMOUNT_INFORCE) AS SumOfSumOfAMOUNT_INFORCE, 
Sum(qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfPUA_FACE) AS SumOfSumOfPUA_FACE, 
Sum(qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfOYT_FACE) AS SumOfSumOfOYT_FACE, TotalDPA = sum(case when qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfNetDefExtraAdj] Is Null then qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfNetDefPremiumAdj] else qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfNetDefPremiumAdj] +qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfNetDefExtraAdj] end), 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfGROSS_ANNLZD_PREM, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfStatNetPremium, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfStatNetPremium]/qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfGROSS_ANNLZD_PREM] AS NetToGrossRatio, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.NetvsGrossInd, 
DPA_NetPrem = case when qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[NetvsGrossInd]='Net' then sum(qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfStatNetPremium]) else sum([qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy].[SumOfGROSS_ANNLZD_PREM]) end, 
qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.ReinType AS ReinType, 
Sum(qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.ReinsAmount) AS SumOfReinsAmount, 
qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.[ReinsAmount]/(qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfAMOUNT_INFORCE]+qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfOYT_FACE]+qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfPUA_FACE]) AS [Reins%], 
qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.ReinsStatRsv AS ReinsStatRsv, 
Sum(qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.SumOfGROSS_ANNLZD_PREM) AS ReinsPrem, qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.PAID_TO_DATE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.VAL_DATE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.ISSUE_DATE


FROM qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re  RIGHT JOIN 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy
ON 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.POLICY_NO = qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.POLICY_NO   
 AND qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.PHASE_CODE = qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.PHASE_CODE AND  
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SUB_PHASE_CODE= qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.SUB_PHASE_CODE 
GROUP BY 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.POLICY_NO, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SUB_PHASE_CODE,
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SchedNP, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.ProdType, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfGROSS_ANNLZD_PREM, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.SumOfStatNetPremium, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfStatNetPremium]/qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfGROSS_ANNLZD_PREM], 
qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.NetvsGrossInd, 
qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.ReinType, 
qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.[ReinsAmount]/(qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfAMOUNT_INFORCE]+qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfOYT_FACE]+qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.[SumOfPUA_FACE]), 
qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.ReinsStatRsv,
 qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.PAID_TO_DATE, 
 qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.VAL_DATE, 
 qryReinsuranceDPA1_izzy.ISSUE_DATE
```

GO

and this is the qry that contains the policy numbers that I want divided by 2 in the above qry.

```
SELECT 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.POLICY_NO, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.SUB_PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.ProdType, 
TotalDPA = Sum(case when [SumOfNetDefExtraAdj] Is Null then [SumOfNetDefPremiumAdj] else [SumOfNetDefPremiumAdj] + SumOfNetDefExtraAdj end), 
Sum(1) AS Expr1
FROM qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re RIGHT JOIN qryReinsuranceDPA1
ON 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.POLICY_NO = qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.POLICY_NO AND 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.PHASE_CODE= qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.PHASE_CODE AND 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.SUB_PHASE_CODE = qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.SUB_PHASE_CODE 
GROUP BY qryReinsuranceDPA1.POLICY_NO, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.SUB_PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.ProdType
HAVING (((Sum(1))<>1))
```

GO

quick example. Say that the Policy number 064543200 is located in the results of that second qry. I then want the number located in first qry in Total DPA assosciated with that Policy number to be divided by 2.

If this is still confusing please let me know and I will try to explain better. Both are views.

Comment: Maybe an In case when somewhere?

Comment: If you want a useful answer then I suggest that you take some time to put your question together properly. The queries you've posted are meaningless without knowledge of the schema and they are probably completely unnecessary to answer your question. Instead, please construct a small example using a couple of dummy tables with one or two columns each and show the results you expect. Ideally, post `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that others can simply copy and paste into SSMS. Although you seem to expect others to help you, they won't unless you make it easy for them.